# I can't type bold-text in Japanese in HTMLEditor (JAVAFX)

Tags: javafx, html-editor

I am using JAVAFX to develop tool.
While I create a screen of HTMLEditor in eclipse,
It does not be "bold-text" when I enter Japanese, although I'm pressing the "Bold-button".

At this moment, I'm choosing the font, MS Gothic, PGothic,
it does not be bold either.

I can type English in bold-text, but I can't type bold-text in Japanese.

I appreciate if you tell me the reason why this thing happens.

Is this kind of a "bug" in the HTMLEditor?

Or somekind of setting problem?

http://bitwalk.sitemix.jp/java_javafx_HTMLEditor.php

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but from the different perspective. It looks like MS Gothic family doesn't have bold font at all. I'm trying to find and embed bold MS Gothic to the rendering PDF, but with no luck, people recommend to use different Japanese font family which supports bold weight.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Font folder of window. Bold Gothic is not supported by Windows.
Check https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8117279